# Significant delay in file updates between processes on Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, page-caching

Consider two independent processes, where Process A handles business and writes logs to a file, while Process B polls the log file and does other tasks (similar to tools like Telegraf, Vector, etc.). When Process A writing new log, I want Process B can read the log in a very low latency, such as 1ms. However in our production environment, delays exceeding 300ms frequently occur.

I think that this involves only the kernel's page cache and doesn't involve physical disk I/O, so it should be very fast, much shorter than 1ms. Why such a significant delay occurs and how it can be improved?

===

I created 2 minimal programs to reproduce this issue. For unknown reasons, I couldn't reproduce the 300ms delay in the test environment, but after running for a few minutes, I still encountered several instances of 3ms delays:

Run the process A to generate log:

```
./makelog tmp1.log
```

Run the process B to poll the log (the 1st column is the delay in usec):

```
./tailog tmp1.log 3000
delay:3225, now:290152, last_read:282002, last_sleep:286233, line:286927 read_len:37
delay:6376, now:813159, last_read:806386, last_sleep:806387, line:806783 read_len:111
delay:3773, now:302125, last_read:293886, last_sleep:298138, line:298352 read_len:37
delay:5931, now:218568, last_read:213272, last_sleep:217525, line:212637 read_len:8
```

The source code of Process A:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int get_now_usec() {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return tv.tv_usec;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("invalid argument\n");
        printf("Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int fd = open(argv[1], O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open file");
        return 1;
    }

    char buf[300];
    while (1) {
        int slen = sprintf(buf, "linestart: %06d log blahblah hello\n", get_now_usec());
        int wlen = write(fd, buf, slen);
        if (wlen != slen) {
            perror("write file");
            return 1;
        }
        usleep(random() % 10000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The source code of Process B:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_now_usec() {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return tv.tv_usec;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("invalid argument\n");
        printf("Usage: %s filename timeout\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char *filename = argv[1];
    int threlhold = atoi(argv[2]);

    int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    char buf[1024*1024];
    int last_sleep = 0;
    int last_read = 0;
    while (1) {
        int len = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
        if (len < 0) {
            perror("read file");
            break;
        }
        if (len == 0) {
            last_sleep = get_now_usec();
            usleep(1000); // 1ms
            continue;
        }
        if (memcmp(buf, "linestart: ", 11) != 0) {
            continue;
        }

        buf[17] = '\0';
        int log_us = atoi(&buf[11]);

        int now = get_now_usec();
        int delay = now - log_us;
        if (delay > threlhold) {
            printf("delay:%d, now:%d, last_read:%d, last_sleep:%d, line:%s read_len:%d\n",
                    delay, now, last_read, last_sleep, buf+11, len);
        }

        last_read = now;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Your Process_A seems to writing an arbitrary length that is less than the block size. Such "short" writes will be fully buffered by the filesystem layer, and may not be accessible by Process_B. In Process_A try the **open()** with the O_SYNC option and/or try adding a **sync()** call after the **write()**.

Comment: @sawdust I tried O_SYNC but it does not help.

Comment: @sawdust No, after write occurred data is in the kernel data structures and immediately available. Specified by POSIX Rationale of `write()`: *Writes can be serialized with respect to other reads and writes. If a read() of file data can be proven (by any means) to occur after a write() of the data, it must reflect that write(), even if the calls are made by different processes.* `O_SYNC` is to enforce synchro to the device.

Comment: @wub That works well for me, launching reader with threshold equals to 300000 (300ms)

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Please forgive my poor English, I does not get your words. What works well for you? I agree with your point about the `write()`, that `O_SYNC` is not necessary. But I does not get your idea about the latter comment.

Comment: I tested your code, and it works well. I ran the taillog part with a threshold equals to 3000 and everything behave perfectly.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Sorry again, but what do you mean about "works well"? Is there any big delay as in my environment, or no big delay as expected?

Comment: Work as expected, no big delay.

Comment: How long did you wait for? More than 20 minutes? Which Linux distro did you test at? I tested on Ubuntu 16 and Ubuntu 20.